# Looking for a complete sample using xAgents to pick apart and use in my application

Tags: xpages

I am very new to xPages and have been reading about xAgents.  I need to write one but am a bit puzzled how to begin.  Things like how to call it once it's written.  Where do I put the code, can I use library code, java code. . .

Does anyone have a complete sample I could see so I can get started with this?  I have most of my code written in an xPage but for security reasons need to put it into an xAgent with sessionAsSigner to access other data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first stop would be the [original article](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/shwl-7mgfbn) that coined the term XAgent (also check the links at the end of the article). Depending on your output the [XMl Helper class](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8MRM48) might be useful too.

**Update/Clarification:** An XAgent is a **front-end** programming technique, not a back-end tool. XAgents get called from browsers (or other devices using HTTP(s)) and need thus be accessible to end-users (ACL applies of course). For functionality your program is calling you use beans and/or SSJS libraries

But taking one step back:

- An XAgent is first and foremost an XPage. So *all* rules for XPages apply:
- You **call it via an URL**, there is no scheduling or event facility. An XAgent is a replacement for the ?OpenAgent URL command, **not** for the other agent use cases
- The XAgent is **always accessible from the outside**, that is its sole purpose, not a device for back-end calls
- since your access to an XAgent is via URL, it isn't an approach for security, security is done using ACL, Readers and Authors. Be careful with using sessionAsSigner, if that is your default you need to revisit your access control ideas
- Since you render all of the XAgent output yourself a typical use case is to obtain the XPages outputstream only and hand this into a function call of a Java (managed) bean

What you might want to look at (again: revisit your security model) is to run an agent from an XPage (comes with a performance penalty) or simply have a managed bean for your sensitive parts

Comment: I actually ready your articles first  I get the basics of it but still a bit unsure how to put it all together.  I have an xPage for users to register for a web site.  Anonymous has Author access to the database.  I need to take information the user entered on the registration page and verify if the data exists in another db that anonymous users don't have access to hence the run as sessionAsSigner.  I though it might make sense to pass the lookup data from the xPage to an xAgent with security to lookup the data as needed.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding what an XAgent is! XAgent is a front-end, user-pointing programming technique, not a backend pointing library that you call from a front-end. The simple approach is to put your code in a SSJS library and call the function there. Another approach is to use a (managed) bean, depending on your Java proficiency and preferences. There is no need for an (X)Agent here. A normal function in your script library will do. Functions are not callable from a browser, but only from SSJS script you write, so security isn't an issue

Comment: As I said earlier I am new to xPages. . .  I thought code be it SSJS library code or directly in the xPage would run with the web user's security.  I am trying to access data with higher security when the web user ( anonymous ) clicks a button thus trying to use sessionAsSigner.  
Prior to xPages I had a web form to capture the data and the submit button would call a webquerysave agent which ran with security of the signed agent.  I would much rather get the performance of xPages but need the same security as the webQuerySaveAgent.

Comment: When you look at your topLevel objects in XPages you find 2 sessions: session and sessionAsSigner. The session object (and database for that matter) run with the user's security. sessionAsSigner however, as the name implies, runs with the signer security. So you can do var lookupDB:Database = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(server,lookupNsfName) and then a lookupDB.getView etc.

Comment: That is what I need.  I was hoping to see a demo of how to create that and call it etc.  Do you know were to find a sample?

Comment: Suggest you ask a new question: How do do a lookup in a database using sessionAsSigner. But it is like the rest, just get the database from that session. var lookupDB:Database = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getSever(),"lookupDB.nsf"); var v:View = lookupDB.getView("viewToLook"); var results = v.getEntryByKey(...); Not different from a LotusScript or Java you would write in an agent - except for the session

Comment: Stephan, thank you for taking all the time to explain.  I greatly appreciate it!  I'll give this a shot!

Comment: feel free to accept the answer (we are in for the points) (^:^)

Answer (score 1):

Using sessionAsSigner in a xAgent could cause a serious security issue. When an anonymous user knows the url of your xagent he can use it to retrieve data from users who are not allowed to do so.

The xAgent is retrieving the data, displaying the data in json or xml structure of some sort ( probably ) and your calling website is then parsing this data. Because of this a user who knows the url of your xagent can use this agent to retrieve data he is not allowed to see. (what If I wrote a php script which calls your agent a couple 100 times to with different parameters? )

I think the best approach would be to have a simple onclick method bound to a button or maybe an onchange which does a partial refresh on a panel where you display the result of the verification.